# RuntimeError: no running event loop Python asyncio.sleep()

Tags: python, python-3.x, scrapy, python-asyncio

I am trying to scrape a website using scrapy + Selenium using async/await, probably not the most elegant code but i get RuntimeError: no running event loop when running asyncio.sleep() method inside get_lat_long_from_url() method, the purpose of using asyncio.sleep() is to wait for some time so i can check if my url in selenium was redirected, any help is appreciated thanks

P.S. - I run the script using scrapy crawl command and not via python filename.py

````
import scrapy
import asyncio

from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC


class MySpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name: str = 'some_name'


    def __init__(self):
        self.options = Options()
        self.options.add_argument('--headless')
        self.driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=self.options)


    def __del__(self):
        self.driver.quit()


    def parse(self, response):
        # spider entrypoint
        # calls parse2 as callback in yield scrapy.Request
        pass


    def parse2(self, response, state):
        links = [link1, link2, link3, link4, link5]
        loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
        tasks = []

        state = city = 'some random value'

        for link in links:
            task = loop.create_task(self.process_requests(link, state, city))
            tasks.append(task)

        asyncio.gather(*tasks)
        loop.run_until_complete(asyncio.wait(tasks))

        for task in tasks:
            yield task.result()


    async def process_requests(self, link, state, city):
        # helper function to get a list of return values in form of coroutines
        return scrapy.Request(
            url=link,
            callback=self.parse3,
            cb_kwargs={'state': state, 'city': city}
        )


    async def parse3(self, response, state, city):
        # some synchronous code
        future = self.get_lat_long_from_url(link)

        # some more synchronous code

        result = await future

        if result:
            # do something
            pass

        # return data: dict for scrapy output


    async def get_lat_long_from_url(self, href: str):
        self.driver.get(href)
        # wait = WebDriverWait(self.driver, 10)
        # wait.until(EC.url_changes(self.driver.current_url))
        
        total = 0 # want to run code for 10 seconds
        # purpose is to check if selenium url was changed / redirected
        while total <= 10:
            await asyncio.sleep(1)
            total += 1
            new_url = self.driver.current_url
            if new_url != href:
                break

        new_url = self.driver.current_url
        return new_url```
````

Want that the code keeps executing asynchronously while asyncio.sleep() happens, instead I get RuntimeError: no event loop

Comment: I don't think you can use asyncio with scrapy.

Comment: @Alexander so do you have any suggestions on how to wait until selenium gets redirected? EC.url_changes gives runtime error every few links due to slow internet

Comment: Why don't you just put it in a while true loop and then break when it finally redirects?

Comment: @Alexander because I get error due to network restrictions from scrapy when I use any sort of selenium functions like url_changes or url_contains, I dont know any other method as of now.